# How to get the mean for a whole dataframe instead of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

How do I get the mean for all of the values (except for NaN) in a pandas dataframe?

[`pd.DataFrame.mean()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) only gives the means for each column (or row, when setting `axis=1`), but I want the mean over the whole thing. And `df.mean().mean()` isn't really the wisest option (see below).

*Note that in my specific real case, the dataframe has a large multiindex, which additionally complicates things. For situations where this does not matter, one could deem @EdChum's answer more straightforward, which might be preferable to a faster solution in some cases.*

**Example code**

```
data1 = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

df.mean()
0    9.0
1    7.0
2    8.0
3    9.0
dtype: float64

df.mean().mean()
7.5

np.arange(16).mean()
7.5
```

works, but if I mask parts of the df (which in reality, is a hundreds of rows/columns correlation matrix which by its nature has half of itself filled with redundant data), it gets funny:

```
triang = np.triu_indices(4)
data2 = np.arange(4.,20.).reshape(4, 4)
data2[triang]=np.nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

df2.mean().mean()
15.0
```

But `(8. + 12. + 13. + 16. + 17. + 18.)/6` is `14.`

How can I best get the "real" mean, except writing some kind of loop that does the above by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
triang = np.triu_indices(4)
data2 = np.arange(4.,20.).reshape(4, 4)
data2[triang]=np.nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

res = np.nanmean(df2)  # 14.0
```

Also possible via `stack`, as described by @EdChum, but slower:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*100000)

%timeit np.nanmean(df2)              # 14.0ms
%timeit df2.stack().dropna().mean()  # 55.7ms
```

If your data is numeric only, you can also remove the Pandas overhead altogether.

Comment: I guess when the doc says "The average is taken over the flattened array by default" I probably really does just use the values and ignores my index. It does result in a single number which also seems realistic for my real data. I'll play around with it for a bit until I understand it though, before I'll accept that answer.

Comment: @JC_CL, `numpy` will not use the index here, it'll only use dataframe values. But do test for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas.Series.dropna) and then call [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
In[201]:
df2.stack().dropna().mean()

Out[201]: 14.0
```

So this converts the df into a single column `Series`, then you can call `dropna` to remove the `NaN` rows, now `mean` will calculate the `mean` correctly.

Comment: This works with the minimal example, but it appears to fail when the df has a large (multi)index. Probably would have to remove that index first.

Comment: @JC_CL well you never stated this in your example so I can only answer what is stated

Comment: You are right. I just wasn't expecting that the indices play a role when I'm just interested in the values. However, your method still works, I just have stack stack upon stack… But I'll take the `np.nanmean(df)` approach, since it's just `62.9 µs per loop`, whereas `df.stack().stack().stack().dropna().mean()` is quite a bit slower at `19.9 ms per loop`.

Comment: @JC_CL I forgot about `np.nanmean` that would be my preferred method here also, not surprising that my method is slower as there are a lot intermediate structures being generated. The only difference is that you keep everything in `pandas` land

Comment: Still, could come in handy at some point. I added a remark to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution similar in spirit to that by @EdChum, but using numpy (which calculates by default [the mean of a flattened array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)):

```
df.to_numpy().mean()
```

If we want to avoid nans, possible solutions are

```
df[df.notna()].to_numpy().mean()
```

or

```
np.nanmean(df.to_numpy())
```

([`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html#numpy.nanmean) is similar to `np.mean`, but does not have a suffix form.)